# Set encoding when converting text file to pdf using itext

Tags: java, itext

I'm working on getting itext to output my UTF-8 encoded text correctly in fact the input file contains symbols like ° and Latin caracters (é,è,à...) .

But i didn't find a solution this is the code i'm using :

```
BufferedReader input = null;
Document output = null;
System.out.println("Convert text file to pdf");
System.out.println("input  : " + args[0]);
System.out.println("output : " + args[1]);
try {
  // text file to convert to pdf as args[0]
  input = 
    new BufferedReader (new FileReader(args[0]));
  // letter 8.5x11
  //    see com.lowagie.text.PageSize for a complete list of page-size constants.
  output = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, 40, 40, 40, 40);
  // pdf file as args[1]
  PdfWriter.getInstance(output, new FileOutputStream (args[1]));

  output.open();
  output.addAuthor("RealHowTo");
  output.addSubject(args[0]);
  output.addTitle(args[0]);

  BaseFont courier = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.COURIER, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
  Font font = new Font(courier, 12, Font.NORMAL);
  Chunk chunk = new Chunk("",font);
  output.add(chunk); 

  String line = "";
  while(null != (line = input.readLine())) {
    System.out.println(line);
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph(line);
    p.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED);
    output.add(p);
  }
  System.out.println("Done.");
  output.close();
  input.close();
  System.exit(0);
}
catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  System.exit(1);
}
}
```

Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: You use `BaseFont.COURIER` with `BaseFont.CP1252` encoding. Have you checked whether the standard 14 Courier font contains all your characters? And whether they occur on code page 1252?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When I look at your code, I see a number of things that are odd.

1. You say you require UTF-8, but you create a `BaseFont` object using `BaseFont.CP1252` instead of `BaseFont.IDENTITY_H` (which is the "encoding" you need when you work with Unicode).
2. You use the standard Type 1 font Courier, which is a font that doesn't know how to render é,è,à... and a font that is never embedded. As documented, the `BaseFont.EMBEDDED` parameter is ignored in this case!
3. You don't use this font with an object that has actual content. The actual content is put into a `Paragraph` that is created using the default font "Helvetica", a font that doesn't know how to render é,è,à...

To solve this, you need to create the `Paragraph` with the appropriate font. That is **NOT** a standard type 1 font, but something like `courier.ttf`. You also need to use the appropriate encoding: `BaseFont.IDENTITY_H`.

Comment: Is it possible to add a unicode string directly to PDF using iText ?

Comment: like this list.add(new ListItem("யுத்தத்திலும் ப்ரனயதிலும் நியமங்கள் நோக்கில்லா \n\nபோரிலும் காதலிலும் சட்டங்களை நோக்க கூடாது"));        document.add(list);

Comment: But in the PDF I got only like this  '________\n\n ______' .. Why? (think __ as spaces because Stackoverflow not supporting long whitespaces )

Comment: You should use iText 7 if you need support for Hindi, Kannada, Tamil, Telugu,... iText 5 doesn't support Indic languages. You also need the pdfCalligraph add-on to process the Indic languages. Read the documentation on the web site. Note: support for Indic languages is **closed source**, we don't offer support for those languages in open source.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I want to know how to use the closed source. The above mentioned code was compiled and executed using iText 7 only. I used maven dependency pom.xml to use iText Library

Comment: How can I get closed source using maven . Also give a sample code link (on iText 7) about how to use any non-roman languages that need UTF-8 Encoding

Comment: I don't have time to answer all your questions @RageshDAntony If you go to the web site, you can download a trial version of pdfCalligraph from our closed source Maveb repository. You can also download a white paper containing several examples. Why do you need someone to spell everything out for you?

Answer (score 2):

Both the reader and the writer should be set to use UTF-8 character set encoding to read/write UTF-8 characters properly. For example,

```
input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(args[0], "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: thank you i wrote this :                                                    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
      input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8")); but it didn't work

Comment: @AmiraGL, can you please also check if the BaseFont you are using supports the characters you are trying to output?