# iText 5.5.0 failed to extract Czech characters

Tags: java, pdf, unicode, encoding, itext

I am trying to extract some text from Czech pdf, but for some characters it returns gibberish, for example ů or ě or č etc...

Originally I am using iText 2.1.7 and failed, so I switched to iText 5.5.0 but still fail...

I tried to crack in the open source code, and this is what it shows:

For example, the `PdfString string` that consists of a single 'ě', the `getByte` method returns a single-length `byte[]` that has integer value -85, and iText converts it to Unicode 256-85 = 171 and returns '«'

Similarly, for the `PdfString string` that consists of a single 'ů', it gives integer value -84 and iText converts it to Unicode 172 = '¬'
(Actually I don't know how is this possible, since ě and ů never go together in a character table...)

This behavior is not universal, the integers from the `getByte` method change along the pdf.

The above example comes from the beginning of page 4 of http://www.seelrc.org:8080/grammar/pdf/stand_alone_czech.pdf

Is there any get around to this problem?
I read many threads which concern "creating Czech PDF" and use something like font with IDENTITY_H, but I only want to extract texts.

Comment: maybe this could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21254628/set-encoding-when-converting-text-file-to-pdf-using-itext

Comment: I read that before. But I mentioned I don't need to create a font to output to PDF... I don't know how the answer from that thread can help.

Comment: If you copy paste the text from Adobe Reader to e.g. Word, it doesn't paste the expected characters. It means something is wrong with the PDF, not with iText or any other text extractor.

Comment: That is actually right, what I copied from Adobe is what I got from iText.... This applies nearly to all Czech pdfs...
But if it can display correctly, how come I cannot get the text out? Is some encoding missing?

Comment: "Display" and "encoding" are only very loosely connected in a PDF. Think of it like this: the numeric value 171 displays vectors in the shape of "ě". If there is no *additional* information in the PDF that states the numerical code "171" (associated with some vector information) actually *represents* Unicode character U+011B, then there is no way to automatically do this translation.

Comment: So how does Adobe know that 171 (sometimes 10, or 50, or...) means displaying "ě", which is coming from a `PDFString` type? I don't know if this is revelant, but it seems before encountering such characters, it invokes a FONTFILE2 font change, with no Encoding information.

Comment: OK I guess, roughly, it means that Adobe tries to display those characters as some kind of images? In that case are there any OCR method in iText to extract them?

Comment: "Adobe" -> "Acrobat". If there is *no* encoding given, then asking for "character #171" draws the 171th character in the font.

Comment: If there is no specific encoding information, then yes: **all** characters are actually only images. Compare with an icon font, such as (the original) WingDings. Typing an "Q" *shows* an airplane, but that does not make it "mean" "Q=airplane".

Comment: All of this is explained in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wxGEEv7ibHE