# Encoding in downloaded pdf generated by itextpdf

Tags: java, angular, maven, encoding, itext

I have a web application using java 8 + maven with eclipse neon and angular 2+. application server is ibm was 9.

To make pdf, I use itextpdf but for some reason, accents are replaced like this :

Prénom => PrÃ©nom

Nationalité => NationalitÃ©

Here is Angular part

```js
generatePDF(obj, options) {
    return this.http.get('/pdf', options)
      .map((response: Response) => {
        const pdfBlob = response.blob();
        const blob = new Blob(['\ufeff', pdfBlob], {
          type: 'application/pdf'
        });
        const pdfName = this.pdfName.transform(obj);
        FileSaver.saveAs(blob, pdfName);
      });
  }
```

How pdf is send by rest

```
@GET
@Path("/pdf")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
public Response pdf(@QueryParam("id") String id) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos;
    try {
        bos = pdfBr.generatePdf(id);
        final ByteArrayInputStream responseStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());
        try {
            bos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        StreamingOutput output = new StreamingOutput() {

            @Override
            public void write(java.io.OutputStream out) throws IOException,
                    WebApplicationException {
                int length;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                while((length = responseStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    out.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }
                out.flush();
                responseStream.close();
            }
        };

        return Response.ok(output).header(
                "Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + "pdf_" + id + ".pdf" + "\"").build();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (DocumentException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Response.ok().build();
```

how pdf is created

```
@Override
public ByteArrayOutputStream generatePdf(String id)
        throws DocumentException, MalformedURLException, IOException {
    Obj obj = objDao.getObj(id);

    Document document = new Document();
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos);
    document.open();

    PdfPTable info = new PdfPTable(new float[] { 100 });

    info.getDefaultCell().setBorder(com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
    info.setWidthPercentage(100);
    final Image logo = Image.getInstance(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/bar.png"));

    logo.scalePercent(0.75f);
    PdfPCell logoCell = new PdfPCell(logo, true);
    logoCell.setBorderWidth(0f);
    logoCell.setBorder(com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
    info.addCell(logoCell);

    document.add(info);

    document.add(new Phrase("\n", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 4, Font.BOLD)));

    PdfPTable objInfo = new PdfPTable(new float[] { 20, 15, 15, 15, 20, 15 });
    objInfo.setWidthPercentage(100);
    objInfo.getDefaultCell().setBorder(com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle.NO_BORDER);

    Font labelFont = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 9, Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC);
    Font valueFont = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 9, Font.NORMAL);

    Font valueFontRed = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 9, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.RED);

    Font valueFontGreen = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 9, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.GREEN);

    objInfo.addCell(new Paragraph("Nom :", labelFont));
    objInfo.addCell(new Paragraph(obj.getLastName(), valueFont));

    objInfo.addCell(new Paragraph("Prénom :", labelFont));
    objInfo.addCell(new Paragraph(obj.getFirstName(), valueFont));

    document.close();
    pdfWriter.close();
    baos.close();

    return baos;
}
```

what i tried :

- Change encoding to utf-8 for java files
- Change encoding to uft-8 for project
- Change encoding.properties file in was 9
- Change content-type for eclipse

Comment: Possible duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21254628/set-encoding-when-converting-text-file-to-pdf-using-itext

Comment: Could it be that your code is UTF-8 encoded but your compiler expects something like Latin-1?

Comment: Already replaced each occurrence of ISO-**** to UTF-8 & documentation of maven say that default value for encoding is UTF-8...

Comment: Does it work when you execute it locally? Maybe your whole environment doesn't have to do with it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add these 2 lines in properties of pom.xml works for me

```
<project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
```